# SSLCipherSuite - more precise definition, need only strong ciphers

Tags: apache-2.4, configuration, cipher

The Apache documentation of SSLCipherSuite seems a little vague and the examples I found on the web make it much worse.  I see a lot of references to "all", long lists of specific ciphers and lots of "!<fill in the blank>" references.  For a simple web server (no vhosts or specific directory specifications, very specific use and limited administrator access) if I use just

SSLCipherSuite HIGH

am I going to get only the cipher suites listed by

openssl ciphers HIGH

or am I going to get other unintended additions that I need to specifically exclude?  (I'm hoping to be able to apply the KISS principle if possible.)  When excluding "all" and "medium", am I understanding the !<fill in the blank> specifications correctly as mainly to prevent the server specification from being over-ridden by other configuration?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on experience, the answer to the first question is yes, it solved the complaints about weak ciphers.